# Titanium appcelerator Payment method

Tags: ios, titanium, payment, appcelerator, credit-card

Is there any module available that can accept credit card and send into paypal for Titanium Appcelerator.I have tried many modules but they dont meet my requirements. Any help would be very helpful.

Requirements are I am building a titanium appcelerator application in which I want customer to pay owner via credit card. So simply its Credit card --> Paypal Money sending. I want to know if there is some module built in titanium that can full fill my requirement.

Comment: what are your requirements ?

Comment: Thanks maazza for responding. Requirements are I am building a titanium appcelerator application in which i want customer to pay owner via credit card. So simply its Credit card --> Paypal Money sending. I want to know if there is some module built in titanium that can full fill my requirement.Thanks

Comment: add as much info as possible when you ask something it improves the odds of someone being able to answer it

Answer (score 0):

There exists a [Ti.Paypal](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.paypal) module. Take a look at it!

Comment: Is this module of Paypal in accelerator works?
https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.paypal

Comment: You can also have a look at https://github.com/AppWerft/Ti.Paypal (Android) and https://github.com/hansemannn/ti.paypal (iOS)

Comment: I have seen these two repo's but my need is to handle adaptive payment in parallel payment. My app let users buy services and pay for the fee and service cost. Is Appcelerator module for paypal not work any more?